# Emulate a CISCO PIX Firewall

Tags: cisco, firewall, gns3

Is it possible to emulate a CISCO PIX 515 firewall with the software GNS3? Provided I have a working image, of course (that's another topic).

Thanks.

Comment: The PIX series was replaced by the ASA 5500 series, as CISCO says in its website. They have almost the same functionality adding some other improvements. Would that be possible to emulate in GNS3? Anyway, the qEmu option seems a good starting point for my original purpose.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a PIX emulation if you need to, and there is still a demand for this functionality in spite of there no longer being "official" support for PIX within GNS3.

Jason Neumann explains the process on the GNS3 community web site at https://community.gns3.com/message/8432#8432

Answer (score 5):

No. However, the pix (and asa) images can be run via qemu. GNS3 does document how to do this. (as well as various youtube videos, and thousands of blogs.)

[I personally don't bother since the real hardware can be found on eBay for next to nothing.]

Comment: The problem is: I need to emulate it for some practical config exercises, at the University, in absence of the real hardware at home.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so.  GNS3 will not allow it.

However, the other answer has a good point.
Buy a firewall online for cheap.
I got a PIX 525 for 28.00 on ebay...

Packet Tracer 6.1 has only one firewall 5505 ASA...
No PIX there either.

Comment: Buying it would be a cheap practical solution. The problem is, the unlimited number of different topologies and configurations one could try in GNS3 networks gives it a much more powerful spectrum of uses, while emulating it.